# Lightweight class-loader for custom class initialization?

Tags: java, ioc-container, classloader

I want to inject some data to static class fields, which are generated from bulk of XML files.

```
class Foo {
    ...
    static MetaData xxx; 
    static MetaData yyy; 
}
```

The injection is very simple, it finds Foo.properties and parse xxx, yyy properties, then constructs the MetaData instances.

I'm not sure if IoC container may help this task, but it seems like not.

Because, the Foo maybe used by classes which are not loaded by IoC container.

My idea is, modify the context class loader to add some specific class initialization codes based on reflection.

Any idea?

**EDIT** There are a lot of IoC containers, I guess some of them may support initialization extensions maybe.

Comment: `Because, the Foo maybe used by classes which are not loaded by IoC container.` This is probably no problem, but IoC requires usually some configuration/annotations and this could be. Can't you do it without modifying the ClassLoader, just by finding all classes or property files, calling Class.forName and doing some reflection? Actually, I'd prefer to avoid it all by creating a Map<Class, Map<String, MetaData>>, if possible.

Comment: No, get rid of Class.forName() is the design purpose. There won't be a Map<Class, *>, the parse/construct process is very fast, and the MetaData is a weak reference inside to reduce memory footprint.

Comment: Why cannot be the xxx, yyy initialized in lazy mode?

Answer (score 0):

xxx, yyy initialized in **lazy mode**.

such as:

```
private static MetaData xxx=null;
public static MetaData getXXX(){
    if(xxx=null){
       xxx=parse("Foo.properties");
    }
    return xxx;
}
```

And if Ioc is a must to your program, [BeanPostProcessors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp) in Spring can be a choice. You could parse file and create MetaData object in BeanPostProcessor.

Comment: There are dozens of MetaData generated in a class from the model, explicitly construct them will pollute the source code.

Comment: P.S. the lazy initialization should be synchronized. See http://bit.ly/gJdSK2. :)